# SQL Sum of Field

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL table as following:

```
INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(1, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 210, 1508989500195);

INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(2, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 220, 1508989500195);

INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(3, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 230, 1508989500195);

INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(4, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 240, 1508989500195);

INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(5, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 250, 1508989500195);

INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(6, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 260, 1508989500195);

INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(7, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 270, 1508989500195);

INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(8, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 280, 1508989500195);

INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(9, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 290, 1508989500195);

INSERT INTO RACUN VALUES(10, 'Gotovina', to_date('02.01.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 300, 1508989500195);
```

I need to calculate the sum of price values(the column after date) of rentals in January 2013. How could this be done?

Comment: aggregate functions (`sum()`) and grouping (`group by`). Google them.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(price) as price_sum FROM RACUN WHERE date > '01-01-2013' AND date < '01-31-2013'
```

Answer (score 1):

See : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Your's might read

```
SELECT SUM(price_column_name) as PriceSum 
FROM table_name 
WHERE date_column_name date > 'MM-DD-YYYY' AND date < 'MM-DD-YYYY'
```

subbing the appropriate fields in of course.

Answer (score 1):

well in sql sum goes like this:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM RACUN where date_column between startDate and endDate
```

since you have not inserted column names i can not adapt it for your case

Or you could extract month and year from the date and use those values in the where clause